# NextJS Middleware Redirect Loop: How to Fix It?

Tags: next.js, middleware, next.js13

I just implemented User-Agent Based Rendering in my nextjs application, i want to get users device info from userAgent in next.js and redirect them to specific page but i  got the error "localhost redirected you too many times.

**it works with matcher: ["/"]**

Here is my `middleware.js` file:

```js
import { NextResponse, userAgent } from "next/server";

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)"],
};

export function middleware(request) {
  const { device } = userAgent(request);
  switch (device.type) {
    case "mobile":
      if (request.nextUrl.clone().pathname !== "mobile") {
        request.nextUrl.pathname = "mobile";
        return NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl);
      }
      break;
    case "tablet":
      if (request.nextUrl.clone().pathname !== "tablet") {
        request.nextUrl.pathname = "tablet";
        return NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl);
      }
      break;
    default:
      if (request.nextUrl.clone().pathname !== "desktop") {
        request.nextUrl.pathname = "desktop";
        return NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl);
      }
      break;
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

I am new to this stuff If possible can you edit the code I provided I would appretiate that.